# index solr facet fields in a separate core

Tags: solr, ontology, faceted-search, hierarchical

I am using solr to provide faceted search on articles. Generally from what I read, the faceted fields need to be indexed together with the rest of the article. However in my case, the faceted fields are derived ontology terms, not in the original content, and I might add additional ontologies as we go.

One solution is to add these new terms into the original articles as new fields, and index whole. However, the ontology terms can change and grow frequently, and reindexing the entire collection could take very long time (one+ month), so I am wondering if I can just index these ontology terms as separate core, without re-indexing the original articles. Is it feasible to  query across multiple cores with hierarchical faceted search?

Thanks!